# Insert radio button value in database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, radio-button

I'm working on a project. Where there is a radio button for Do you have passport. If user select yes then further text boxes and a button to upload passport image is shown to user else they hide.
My question is that when user select yes and fill complete details then it works properly and when user select no button or other case when user select yes but doesn't select image for upload then rest data he/she fills in the text box doesn't making entry to database. I will be very thankful for this to remove my bug.
I stored image directly in database by using BLOB type.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
 $conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","db_dat");

 $passno="";
 $doi="";
 $doe="";
 $poi="";
 if (isset($_POST['pass']))
 {
  $passno=$_POST['pass'];
 }
 if (isset($_POST['dateofissue']))
 {
  $doi=$_POST['dateofissue'];
 }
 if (isset($_POST['dateofexpiry']))
 {
  $doe=$_POST['dateofexpiry'];
 }
 if (isset($_POST['issueplace']))
 {
  $poi=$_POST['issueplace'];
 }
 if(isset($_POST['yeshave']))
 {
  $selectedValue =$_POST['yeshave'];
 }
 ?> 

<?php
 //image script
 if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0)
 {
  $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
  $tmpName = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
  $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
  $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

  $fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
  $image = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
  $image = addslashes($image);
  fclose($fp);

  if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
  {
   $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
  }
  //imagescriptend
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";
  $dbname = "db_dat";

  $conn=mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

  $query = "INSERT INTO upload (name, size, type, image,passport_no,
      dateofissue,dateofexpiry,placeofissue, having_passport ) ".
  "VALUES ('$fileName', '$fileSize', '$fileType', '$image','"
     .$passno."','".$doi."','".$doe."','".$poi."','".$selectedValue."')";

  mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die('Error, query failed'); 

  echo "<br>File $fileName uploaded<br>";
 } //ifissetpost submit end
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- Set the viewport width to device width for mobile -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name="yeshave"]').on('click', function() {
     $('#textboxes').toggle($(this).val() == 'yes');
    });
   });
   });
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
   href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui1.com/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
   $(function() {
    $( "#datepickerfordoi" ).datepicker();
   });
  </script>
  <script>
   $(function() {
    $( "#datepickerfordoe" ).datepicker();
   });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>Do you haver passport:</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="yeshave" value="yes"> Yes</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="yeshave" value="no"> No</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  <divine id="textboxes" style="display: none">
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td>Passport No:</td>
     <td>
      <input type="text" name="pass">
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Date of Issue:</td>
     <td>
      <input type="text" name="dateofissue" id="datepickerfordoi"> 
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Date of expiry:</td>
     <td> <input type="text" name="dateofexpiry" id="datepickerfordoe"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td width="246"><br><br>
      <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000">
      <input name="userfile" type="file" id="userfile"> 
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </divine>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>
    <td>
     <input name="submit" type="submit" class="fsSubmitButton" 
      id="upload" value=" submit ">
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please check your code for SQL Injections. You don't want to get hacked.

Comment: Please avoid horizontal scrollbars. It makes the reading of posts harder.

Comment: Sir actually my submit button works on image upload in submit button name="upload" so when user doesn't select image no data is posted

Comment: So you figured it out? Answered your own question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cauz my image and rest other text boxes that open are working on one submit button whose name is upload and in my image script I set upload . So If user doesn't choose a image it doesn't work properly